# Directory structure for large number of files

Tags: php, filesystems, directory

I made one site... where i am storing user uploaded files in separate directories like

user_id = 1

so

img/upload_docs/1/1324026061_1.txt

img/upload_docs/1/1324026056_1.txt


Same way if 

user_id = 2

so

img/upload_docs/2/1324026061_2.txt

img/upload_docs/2/1324026056_2.txt

...

n

So now if in future if I will get 100000 users then in my upload_docs folder I will have 100000 folders.

And there is no restriction on user upload so it can be 1000 files for 1 user or 10 files any number of files...


so is this proper way?
Or if not then can anyone suggest me how to store this files in this kind of structure???

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is name the images UUIDs and create subfolders based on the names of the files. You can do this pretty easily with [`chunk_split`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.chunk-split.php). For example, if you create a folder every 4 characters you would end up with a structure like this:

```
img/upload_docs/1/1324/0260/61_1.txt 
img/upload_docs/1/1324/0260/56_1.txt
```

By storing the image name 1324026056_1.txt you could then very easily determine where it belongs or where to fetch it using `chunk_split`.

This is a similar method to how git stores objects.

As code, it could look something like this.

```
// pass filename ('123456789.txt' from db)
function get_path_from_filename($filename) {
    $path = 'img/upload_docs';
    list($filename, $ext) = explode('.', $filename); //remove extension
    $folders = chunk_split($filename, 4, '/'); // becomes 1234/5678/9
    // now we store it here
    $newpath = $path.'/'.$folders.'/'.$ext;
    return $newpath;
}
```

Now when you search for the file to deliver it to the user, use a function using these steps to recreate where the file is (based on the filename which is still stored as '123456789.txt' in the DB).

Now to deliver or store the file, use `get_path_from_filename`.

Comment: this is gonna be a directory with 10000 files, which doesn't seem too good solution.

Comment: No, it will end up being several directories with a handful of files each. If it works for git storing several thousand objects, why wouldn't it work for 10000 users with several images?

Comment: Ah I see your mistake. Reread the question - it's not the image name that matters ;)

Comment: Read my answer - the image name simply dictates the folder structure. This will split the folder structure up in a way that there won't be 100000 folders within a single folder.

Comment: Read my comment.  image name doesn't dictate anything

Comment: Guys thanks for your support but still i am confuse what to do??? my image name is timestamp_userid.jpg or .txt anything... so you all are saying that without adding user_id as folder name i devide name of the image into 1(letter)/4(letters)/4(letters)/file ???

Comment: even can i reverse the timestamps and user first 2(letters)/3(letters)/3(letters)/file name??? so by doing this there will be max 99 folders in upload_doc folder at first level then in second level in all 99 folders will have max 999 folder and in third level those 999 folders will have max 999 folders in each and those last third level folders will contain the files... so as per 1324026056_2.txt will store in upload_docs/65/065/042/31/1324026056_2.txt... what you all say???

Comment: I updated the answer to hopefully bring some clarity as to what I was suggesting. The DB stores the filename and you script determines where it actually lives. *OR* you could use this script and store that path in the DB instead. Your choice.

Answer (score -1):

```
img/upload_docs/1/0/10000/1324026056_2.txt
img/upload_docs/9/7/97555/1324026056_2.txt
img/upload_docs/2/3/23/1324026056_2.txt
```

Comment: can you explain your answer??? as i did not get this 1/0/10000 and 9/7/97555 and 2/3/23 ... what are those refer to???

Comment: Shame on me, I thought it's obvious.