# Multiple Directories or One - data storage and access

Tags: database, algorithm, get

This is more of a algorithm question, but I am trying to figure out what would be the most efficient for a large database of pictures. Would it make more sense to store a lot of files all under one directory (ex:pictures/userid_pic_profile.png) or multiple directories for a few number of files (ex: userid/profile.png userid/avatar.png)?

Comment: duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9821947/directory-structure-for-large-number-of-files   ?

Comment: Kind of, but still doesn't answer the efficiency question. It's pretty much just suggestions (as is the one I marked as the answer because I agree with it from experience).

Comment: More efficient for what?  Are you accessing the pictures one at a time?  Are you trying to analyze large subsets of them?  Is there a likely ordering in the access?  Are the files changing over time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For organizational reasons alone you should be using multiple directories.

Additionally, for some operating systems having a very large number of files in one directory can cause real slowdowns when listing and searching for files (I am talking about thousands and tens of thousands of files in a single directory).

Comment: Is there any algorithms or math to back this up? I was going to do that based on just intuition, but I would love to see if this has been proven in some way.

Comment: @user1470511 - The slowness? Experience ;)

Comment: Depends highly on how a particular file system implements its directory structure. Some use an unsorted, linear, list of file names. Some use a sorted, linear, list of file names. Some go even further and use a B-tree (or similar), keyed by file name. In the first case, the average access is O(N) on the number of files, in the second and third, O(log N) should be achievable, with (probably) better constants in the B-tree case.

Comment: @Vatine - Sure. Still, for organizing stuff, you don't want to have so many files in one directory.

Comment: @Oded - You are entirely correct. When I was doing stuff that tended to generate oodles to multiple oodles of files on a linux server, I ended up building a hierarchical structure based on prefixes of filenames (well, phone numbers, byut...)